# How to resize image in swift picker menu style

Tags: swift, image, svg, swiftui, picker

I want to use a image beside some text in my picker, but image is scaled up and I can't resize it with .resizable .frame and ... .
How can i fix this problem? I use both svg and png format and  neither of those don't working properly.

I using image from asset

[image: here is the screen shot]
[image: and its ok when I tapped on it]

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var array = ["one", "two", "three", "four"]
    @State var selection: String = "one"
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Picker("Select",selection: $selection) {
                ForEach(array, id: \.self) { item in
                    HStack {
                        Text(item)
                            Image("BTC")
                                .resizable()
                                .clipped()
                    }
                   
                }
            }
            .pickerStyle(.menu)
            .padding(.trailing)
            
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried adding a frame constraint to the HStack in addition to .resizable and .frame on the image? Also, make sure you add the appropriate .aspectRatio to the image.

Comment: yes I tried adding frame to Hstack and it not working too. but I don't tried to add aspectRatio to image yet.

Comment: also aspect ratio don't help me.

Comment: add `.resizable` then `.aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)` then your .frame, in that order and see what that does

Comment: @NicolasGimelli I did it but there is no change after running app again.

Comment: I don't have my mac on me so I can't test, but I'll give it a look this evening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Menu` for this purpose:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var array = ["one", "two", "three", "four"]
    @State var selection: String = "one"
    var body: some View {
        Menu(content: {
            Picker("Select",selection: $selection) {
                            ForEach(array, id: \.self) { item in
                                HStack {
                                    Text(item)
                                    Image("BTC")
                                }
                               
                            }
                        }
        }, label: {
            Text(selection)
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: If you add image in label you'll get the same

Comment: I did it and add a HStack in label.
it works and when i adding resizable, aspectRatio and Frame modifier to image that image scaling properly.

Comment: @Asperi we can resize the image by following this answer

Answer (score 2):

If you use the old style for the picker menu (ie. new page to select instead of popup menu), this behavior does not happen.
I think it's a bug with the new ios 16 behavior.

Try to apply this to your picker :

```
.pickerStyle(.navigationLink)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is by-default Menu behavior. Use either SF images, like

```
ForEach(array, id: \.self) { item in
    Label(item, systemImage: "bitcoinsign.circle")
}
```

[image: demo1]

or raster image with small original size, like

```
ForEach(array, id: \.self) { item in
    Label(item, image: "bitcoin")  // in Assets 24x24
}
```

[image: demo2]

Comment: I using collection of images and I can't use SFsymbols for this project, so i have to resize original images? have you recommended platform for do it?

Comment: Using Label in picker seems to not display images on MacOS.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking for a **macOS (App Kit)** solution.

##### NSImage extension

```swift
import Foundation
import AppKit

extension NSImage {
    func scalePreservingAspectRatio(targetSize: NSSize) -> NSImage {
        let widthRatio = targetSize.width / size.width
        let heightRatio = targetSize.height / size.height
        
        let scaleFactor = min(widthRatio, heightRatio)
        
        let scaledImageSize = NSSize(
            width: size.width * scaleFactor,
            height: size.height * scaleFactor
        )
        
        let newImage = NSImage(size: scaledImageSize)
        newImage.lockFocus()
        self.draw(
            in: NSRect(origin: .zero, size: scaledImageSize),
            from: NSRect(origin: .zero, size: self.size),
            operation: .copy,
            fraction: 1.0
        )
        newImage.unlockFocus()
        
        return newImage
    }
}
```

##### ResizedImage View

```swift
import SwiftUI

/// Image resized to a specific size
struct ResizedImage: View {
    let resourceName: String
    let width: Int
    let height: Int
    
    init(_ resourceName: String, width: Int, height: Int) {
        self.resourceName = resourceName
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        if let image = NSImage(named: resourceName) {
            let imageResized = image.scalePreservingAspectRatio(targetSize: NSSize(width: width, height: height))
            Image(nsImage: imageResized)
        } else {
            // Default questionmark if image is not found
            Image(systemName: "questionmark.square")
        }
    }
}
```